# Jquery Mouse Over/Out for loop

Tags: jquery, css, html, for-loop

I'm new to `jquery` and found the following code to change a `div` background on `mouseover` and `mouseout`

```
(document).ready(function(){
         $(".t8").mouseover(function(){
             $(".scover8").css("background-color", "rgba(0,24,60,0.60)");
         });
    $(".t8").mouseout(function(){
             $(".scover8").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.30)");
         });
    });
```

This works great but I need it for 9 `div's`, so instead of copy and pasting this code I want to use a for loop. I've found several examples on this website but I find it hard to translate it for the code i want to use.

Can somebody help me with this ?
Thanks!

HTML CODE (this is repeated 9 times .t1 .scover1  / .t2 .scover2 etc.):

```
<div class="t8" onclick="location.href='index.php?page=databank';" style="cursor:pointer;">
           <div class="scover8">
              <h1><a href="index.php?page=databank">Databank</a></h1><br>
              <h2>Download hier beeld & informatie materiaal.</h2><br>
              <h3>Omschrijvingen, Product Foto's etc.</h3>        
           </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you show your html markup?

Comment: Can't you assign the same class to all divs, and then change the backround of the inner element of the pointed element (**this**)? Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Give the divs a common class to trigger mouse over/out on, then do `.addClass()` & `.removeClass()` instead on mouse over/out, create corresponding classes in css for different background colours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without replicate your code you can use a start with selector:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   beginning exactly with a given string.

and the manipulate its child element using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Code:

```
$("div[class^='t']").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find("div[class^='scover']").css("background-color", "rgba(0,24,60,0.60)");
});
$("div[class^='t']").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find("div[class^='scover']").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.30)");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ULEu7/

Comment: @user3045383 your are welcome! If solved consider to mark the answer as accepted (usng the tick near the answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Call this function
changebackgroundmouseover(".t8",".scover8");
changebackgroundmouseout(".t8",".scover8");

//functiondefination
Function changebackgroundmouseover(element, hoverelement){
element.mouseover(function(){
         hoverelement.css("background-color", "rgba(0,24,60,0.60)");
     });
}

//functiondefination
    Function changebackgroundmouseout(element, hoverelement){
    element.mouseout(function(){
             hoverelement.css("background-color", "rgba(0,24,60,0.60)");
         });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign this event to every element with the same class. Where you use "this" to find the inner element to change its background.

It's better to change your background with classes than inline styling. Also i use the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function, as the hover function already defines mouseover and mouseout:

**jQuery**

```
$(".t").hover(function () 
{
     $(this).find('.scover').addClass('bgGrey');
}, function()
{
     $(this).find('.scover').removeClass('bgGrey');            
})
```

**Css**

```
.scover
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}

.scover.bgGrey
{
    background-color: rgba(0,24,60,0.60);
}
```

Where there is a default background when not hovered.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aeyK/4)

---

However you might want to do this with pure css. Here an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/2aeyK/2)**.